# Can a function have a domain and codomain of binary numbers?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, notation

I saw a thread regarding functions and I have a related question.

**Is it possible to have a function where the domain and the codomain are binary numbers?**

> For a decimal number $x\in \{0, 1, \dots, 2^n-1\}$ we have the binary respresentation
>   \begin{align}
> x &= x_02^0 + x_12^1 + x_22^2 +\ldots+ x_{n-1}2^{n-1} \\
> &= x_0 x_1 \cdots x_{n-1}
> \end{align}
>   where $x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1}\in\{0,1\}$.
>   We also have a second binary number
>   \begin{align}
> y &= y_02^0 + y_12^1 + y_22^2 +\ldots+ y_{n-1}2^{n-1} \\
> &= y_0 y_1 \cdots y_{n-1}
> \end{align}
>   where $y_0,\ldots,y_{n-1}\in\{0,1\}$.

**Question 1:**

Can we now have a function with the domain $\{x\}$ and the codomain $\{y\}$? I.e.
$$
f:\{x\} \rightarrow \{y\} \tag 1
$$

**Question 2:**

Is the function notation in $(1)$ equivalent to the following:
$$
f:\{x_02^0 + x_12^1 + x_22^2 +\ldots+ x_{n-1}2^{n-1}\} \rightarrow \{y_02^0 + y_12^1 + y_22^2 +\ldots+ y_{n-1}2^{n-1}\} \tag 2
$$
$$
f:\{x_0x_1\cdots x_{n-1}\} \rightarrow \{y_0y_1\cdots y_{n-1}\} \tag 3
$$
If so, which notation is most correct/common?

Comment: Why do you think a function cannot have a binary domain and codomain? And the common notation is $F: \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}$. For example $x_1 \land x_2$ is a function given as  $F : \{0,1\}^2 \rightarrow \{0,1\} $

Comment: Here's a far more general result. **Theorem:** Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty sets. Then there exists a function $f:A \rightarrow B.$ **Proof:** Choose $b \in B$ and define $f:A \rightarrow B$ by $f(x) = b$ for each $x \in A$ (i.e. $f$ is a certain constant function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is the same, you are just representing domain and codomain in two different ways.

$$f:\{0\} \rightarrow \{1\} = f:\{(0)_{10}\} \rightarrow \{(1)_{10}\}=f:\{(00)_{2}\} \rightarrow \{(01)_{2}\}$$

$\textbf{Answer 1:}$ yes.

$\textbf{Answer 2:}$ they are both correct, the usage depends on the context.

Comment: In my post the domain and range was not equal, $x\neq y$. But can the domain and range be the same or does it violate the definition of a function? For example $f: \{x\} \rightarrow \{x\}$?

Comment: They can be the same. Your $f$ maps $x$ to $x$ and it is a valid function.